# Added .cu extension into Text Editor and still no syntax highlighting for CUDA

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, syntax, cuda, text-editor

So I have been getting a little frustrated at trying to get the syntax of .cu files for CUDA to highlight. I have added the .cu extension to the Text Editor file extensions as instructed by many others who have had trouble getting the syntax highlighted, and this still does not bring up highlighting for CUDA .cu source codes. I have tried using Visual Studio 2010 and Visual Studio 2012 with no luck. In 2010 the C++ syntax is highlighted like normal with a .cu extension, but no intellisence when typing and no CUDA syntax highlighting. In 2012 the code shows up as a text document with no highlighting or intellisence for both C++ and CUDA. Another thing that is unusual about VS2012 is that if I change the extension back to a .cpp the CUDA syntax highlights and intellisence works but the code will not compile because it is a .cpp.

So my question comes down to the same thing others have asked before, how do I get the syntax for .cu files to highlight? And remember I have already changed the extension in the Text Editor.

Thank you for your help, and if someone can help me solve this problem I will be very happy!

Comment: I was hoping there was a way to do this without going into regedit because usually that is a really bad idea.

Comment: The link I mentioned [here](http://www.ademiller.com/blogs/tech/2010/10/visual-studio-2010-adding-intellisense-support-for-cuda-c/) doesn't make use of regedit.  It's certain that just changing the file extension, as you state in your question, is not enough, and I don't find any instructions on the web that suggest that is all that's needed.